# Checking for completed nav controller animation

Tags: uitableview, ios5, pushviewcontroller, nsindexpath

I now know that If you push a view controller onto a navigation controller with animation, you must wait until that animation has completed before pushing another view controller otherwise you get warnings and possibly unexpected results.

How do you check to see if the nav controller animation has completed such to avoid this issue?

Thanks

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    // ...


    //Make sure animation has completed before sending message below


[[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:NO];

//...

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rally want to push one VC at a time (nice movement to the right over many VCs) you can implement the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` in a controller class (app delegate will do), assign it/yourself to `self.navigationController.delegate`. UINavigationController will invoke `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` after each push.

Answer (score -1):

I used an alternative method that has worked quite well for me. Just wrap the `pushViewController:animated:` call in the `animations:` argument of `[UIView animateWithDuration:animation:completion`. Put whatever you need to run on completion, such as pushing the subsequent controller which is what I am doing, in `completion:`.

In my case, I run the whole thing in a method that takes an array (NSMutableArray) with the list of controllers to push as the argument. In the `completion:` block the method pops the first element from the array (`objectAtIndex:0` and `removeObjectAtIndex:0`) and calls itself with the remainder of the array.

It's a fun [continuation-passing-style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) implementation :)
One thing to note though is that at the end of the animation the content of the new navigation controller may not be fully loaded, so this method is only reliable if your pushes are independent of that content.

Comment: On iOS 7 the completion block is executed before the animation has finished.